# Multicast causes link down on Mikrotik RB2011UiAS-RM switch2

Tags: multicast, mikrotik

I am trying to simply push multicast traffic through the second switch of the router... for now I connected swtich 2 port 8 to my ISP router iPTV port and port9 to SagemonUHD88 IPTV decoder. I set master port port 6, and added slaves port 8,9.

I removed all ports in switch2 from default bridge (no bridges beside).
After few second of multicast traffic the log clamin link down... and goes on an on every few second. I tried firmware 6.38.5 and 6.37.5. Both the same issue.

Just to be sure, I got connector between two RJ-45 plugs so when I disconnect the cables from mikrotik and connect it directly it works without any issues (I mean, the video on TV goes smoothly, no breaks).

I wanted it to just have wirespeed. When I will replace the default router (the Livebox 2.0 fro my ISP) i will try push tagged vlan with that multicast and untag on the port to the IPTV decoded. However for now I am now able to do that and as far as I see RB2011 can only tag frames on the way out from switch (egress), so no way for internal tagging the frames from specific port.

```
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,calc Begin calculation 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event Link up 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event     interface=ether8 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event Update 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event     interface=ether8 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event Link up 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event     interface=ether9 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event Update 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,event     interface=ether9 
mar/24 00:54:55 route,debug,calc End calculation 
mar/24 00:54:56 interface,info ether6-master link up 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event Interface change 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event     interface=ether6-master 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event     status=UP,RUNNING 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event     mtu=1500 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,calc Begin calculation 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event Link up 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event     interface=ether6-master 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event Update 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,event     interface=ether6-master 
mar/24 00:54:56 route,debug,calc End calculation 
mar/24 00:55:01 interface,info ether6-master link down 
mar/24 00:55:01 interface,info ether8 link down 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Interface change 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether6-master 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     status=UP 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     mtu=1500 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Interface change 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether8 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     status=UP 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     mtu=1500 
mar/24 00:55:01 interface,info ether9 link down 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Interface change 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether9 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     status=UP 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     mtu=1500 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,calc Begin calculation 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Link down 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether6-master 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Update 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether6-master 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Link down 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether8 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Update 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether8 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event Link down 
mar/24 00:55:01 route,debug,event     interface=ether9
```

Pics:
[image: Network scheme]

Comment: Have you asked Microtik support about this?

Comment: You are right, I should have done it at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, that version 6.38.5 , 6.37.5 , 6.39rc5 all contain the same issue with pushing multicast on RB2011 to 'switch2 cpu'. They claimed that it had been nailed and fix is going to be a part of the next release.
EOT

EDIT: Already checked, the provided fix works:

```
What's new in 6.39rc62 (2017-Apr-04 14:09):
*) ethernet - fixed rare switch chip hang (could cause port flapping);
```